# Riddle Number One

Tags: riddle

I created this riddle in hopes that you all can deduce the answer.

> I lack all meaning,
>
> yet my meaning is the same.
>
> The cold depths of space shall contain my name.

**What am I?**

Comment: I'm thinking along the lines of nothing, vacuum, or ditto. Something like that.

Comment: @duck you should post that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Duck Sadly it is neither of those solutions.

Comment: Just edited formatting

Comment: Thank you. I'm still learning how to use this site.

Answer (score 7):

Is it:

> the letter i?

I lack all meaning, yet my meaning is the same

> of course, the letter I only has the meaning 'i' has

The cold depths of space shall contain my name

> The word universe has the letter i in it

What am I

> i is I!

Comment: Although I enjoyed reading your detailed solution, the answer is not the letter "i". Great answer, nonetheless!

Comment: I cannot upvote just yet, for my profile is still in need of reputation points in order to do such. However, I shall upvote it once I am allowed to do so!

Comment: As promised, you are now upvoted!

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> "Nothing"?

It lacks all meaning. Yet it's meaning is the same.

> "Nothing" is a word that means nothing. It's meaning is that it has no meaning.

The cold depths of space shall contain my name.

> This one is pretty obvious to me. Space is mostly nothing.

Comment: The answer presented is incorrect, yet is still an enjoyment to read. I love the simplicity of the answer!

Answer (score 3):

> It could be empty or emptyness.

I lack all meaning,

> The meaning of empty actually means something lacking.

yet my meaning is the same.

> And still it means just this.

The cold depths of space shall contain my name.

> And the space is pretty much empty.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it space?
>  It lacks all meaning. Yet it's meaning is the same.
>  Space is contained in the name "cold depths of space"

Answer (score 2):

Could it be

> Void

Since,

> To be devoid of meaning is to lack meaning

And

> Space is sometimes referred to as the void